# Formatar data em laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tenho esse retorno e quero converter de modo a salvar a data no banco **ANO**-**MES**-**DIA**

```
$dataOs = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->data));
```

Quando imprimo assim `dd($dataOs);` as vezes sai da forma certa **2018-11-02** e as vezes sai assim **1970-01-01**, só que em todos os testes que realizei testando pelo `dd($request->data)` a data vem correta parece que é algo na conversão não sei explicar?

Comment: se a data volta 1970-01-01 é por que o $request->data esta passando algo que ele não identifica como data e dai da pau na conversão. tenta printar na tela o $request->data e en seguida o $dataOs  e vai fazendo o debug disso

Comment: já fiz isso e por incrivel que pareça do request a hr que print aparece a data certa mas no $dataOs da o erro 1970-01-01  sabe, fiz esse teste para verificar

Comment: faz assim echo $request->data." | ".$dataOs."<hr>";

Comment: me manda o q apareceu

Comment: `$request->data` isso sai qual resultado?

Comment: Pessoal achei o problema, devido  a primeira conversão que usava as // convertendo de - para / notei que era esse o problema, quando passei só - convertendo de 2018-02-10 para 10-02-2018 resolveu acredito que de alguma forma as / estava dando algum conflito

Answer (score -2):

O Laravel já vem com um biblioteca para se trabalahar com datas, é bem fácil de se utilizar. [Documentação.](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)
Para converter no formato que você precisa você pode trabalhar com os [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)
diretamente em seu model, ficaria mais ou menos assim :

```
 function setDataAttribute($value){
       $dia = substr($value, 8, 2);
       $mes = substr($value, 5, 2);
       $ano = substr($value, 0, 4);

       this->attributes['data'] = Carbon::create($ano, $mes, $dia, 0, 0);

   }
```

Obs: Não testei o código pra ver se está funcionando, mas a idéia é essa. Desta forma você não precisa ficar tratando isto no controller. Suponhamos que você tenha que integrar via API sua aplicação, fazendo desta forma você não precisa se preocupar em converter o campo data novamente porque já esta pronto.